# c# foreign key annotation with Type (not String)

Tags: c#, annotations, foreign-keys, type-safety

I see that you can use

```
[ForeignKeyAttribute("foreignKeyName")]
```

But I am wondering if there is one with *Type* rather than *string*?

For safer refactoring...

Or is there a good use to use *string*?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean that you want to know when the name changes or other changes in the compilation error that its value should be changed, it is better to use Fluent Api

Answer (score 0):

could you make your own custom attribute that inherits from foreign key attribute and overload the constructor? 
I've not tested it but you could maybe try something like this:

```
public class ForeignKeyTypeAttribute : ForeignKeyAttribute
{
    public ForeignKeyTypeAttribute(string name) : base(name)
    { }

    public ForeignKeyTypeAttribute(Type t) : base(t.GetType().Name)
    { }
}
```